# Hiding div with apostrophe in title

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a problem with hiding a div that contains an apostrophe in the name. To hide the use this code :

```
$("div[data-title='Contact']").hide()
```

Everything works perfectly, but the problem occurs just when the div is called an apostrophe. I've tried several forms (see below), but none of them does not work.

```
$("div[data-title='Offer&amp;apos;s']").hide()
$("div[data-title='Offer/'s']").hide()
$("div[data-title='Offer's']").hide()
```

Are there any other ways by which they could refer to the appropriate div?

---

I should add that when I view the page source - the title is saved in this format :

```
 data-title="Offer&amp;apos;s"
```

I checked :

```
 &amp;apos;
 /'
 //'
 \'
 \\'
 '
```

And nothing....

Comment: Have you tried using a backslash (`\\`)?

Comment: Weird. `$("div[data-title='Offer's']").hide();` works fine on jsFiddle.

Comment: Guess: maybe it's the ampersand that gets expanded or parsed. Escaping it (`\&`) should not work, as it's not a usual to-be-escaped character. Maybe expanding it again? `&amp;amp;`...

Comment: Ah, wait. The format the string is *visible* should not matter (i.e., I'm sure in the internal representation it does not say `&amp;`). Try double-escaping then: `\\'`. A single escape `\'` gets stripped out by Javascript's string parser.

Comment: Sadly, still nothing :(

Comment: In source code on webpage, apostrophe represented by "&amp;apos;"

Comment: How are you outputting your js? If it's being echoed/printed with some server side language, it may automatically encode the characters. The fiddle provided in @KyleEmmanuels [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24970366/1165646) works fine, even if the apostrophe is escaped (\'). http://jsfiddle.net/W29AE/8/

Comment: Im using Tampermonkey in Chrome. Works perfect with simple titles, but when title contains an apostrophe - the script does not hide this div

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attribute value, as it appears in your source, is `Offer&amp;apos;s`. This is tricky; it looks like a character reference, but it's *doubly* encoded. The `'` is encoded into `&apos;`, but the `&` in `&apos;` is then encoded into `&amp;`.

When the HTML parser decodes character references, it only decodes them *once*. So the resulting attribute value really is `Offer&apos;s`. The `&apos;` is exactly how it appears: an ampersand, followed by the character sequence "apos", followed by a semicolon. This string is not further decoded into the `'` character.

The value you use in your attribute selector needs to match the value `Offer&apos;s`, not `Offer's`, and certainly not the doubly-encoded `Offer&amp;apos;s` as it appears in the source. Therefore, the correct selector is:

```
$("div[data-title='Offer&apos;s']").hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `$("div[data-title='Offer\'s']").hide();`.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. I should add that when I view the page source - the title is saved in this format - data-title="Offer&amp;apos;s"

Answer (score -1):

`$("div[data-title='Offer\'s']").hide();` works.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W29AE/9/)

Here is a screenshot also:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It does not work. I should add that when I view the page source - the title is saved in this format - data-title="Offer&amp;apos;s"

Comment: Thanks. It's works on fiddle, but not on my webpage. Please - use as data-title this "Offer&amp;apos;s". On ur fiddle i still see "Offer's" . Also, i can send u via PM link to this webpage.

Comment: This cannot possibly work as the quotes are conflicting.

Comment: You keep updating your fiddle, but not once have you touched the code in your answer. Perhaps that might be causing confusion here?

Comment: That means I was busy trying to answer. i gave the fiddle, so it can be as an updated answer.

Comment: You revised the fiddle link *in your answer* at least twice - it's in the revision history. If you're going to neglect the answer part of your answer while editing, then you're essentially posting a link-only answer, no?

Comment: I updated it with the latest. we are here to help, not to be meddlesome.